# How to get value without subdata?

Tags: python, json, parsing

trying to got these data from my json:

```
O2FDSFDSN47U-BFSDFSDWO3-TTFSDFS245H
OIBKDFSDFS2B-K6A2FSDFSDO-2GPFSDFSNES
OSZZEE-FDSDQUNAZ-OHDSQDQS2NDS
```

using `print(data['result']['open'])` : 
but returns all data after the `id`.

These `id` are still moving, I can't guess them.
Using regex seems not to be a good idea

nothing else, but when using my python parser, I always got the subdata.

```
{
  "error": [],
  "result": {
    "open": {
      "O2FDSFDSN47U-BFSDFSDWO3-TTFSDFS245H": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "3",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fcib"
      },
      "OIBKDFSDFS2B-K6A2FSDFSDO-2GPFSDFSNES": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "1.5",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "2.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      },
      "OSZZEE-FDSDQUNAZ-OHDSQDQS2NDS": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "9",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how to grab theses without nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
s = '''{
  "error": [],
  "result": {
    "open": {
      "O2FDSFDSN47U-BFSDFSDWO3-TTFSDFS245H": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "3",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fcib"
      },
      "OIBKDFSDFS2B-K6A2FSDFSDO-2GPFSDFSNES": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "1.5",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "2.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      },
      "OSZZEE-FDSDQUNAZ-OHDSQDQS2NDS": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "9",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      }
    }
  }
}'''

data = json.loads(s)
```

---

```
>>> data['result']['open'].keys()
dict_keys(['O2FDSFDSN47U-BFSDFSDWO3-TTFSDFS245H', 'OIBKDFSDFS2B-K6A2FSDFSDO-2GPFSDFSNES', 'OSZZEE-FDSDQUNAZ-OHDSQDQS2NDS'])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed using [regex to parse your json is not the good approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions), what you need to do is , after loading the json into an dictionary object, to access all the keys via `dict.keys()`.

```
import json

inStr = """{
  "error": [],
  "result": {
    "open": {
      "O2FDSFDSN47U-BFSDFSDWO3-TTFSDFS245H": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "3",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fcib"
      },
      "OIBKDFSDFS2B-K6A2FSDFSDO-2GPFSDFSNES": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "1.5",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "2.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      },
      "OSZZEE-FDSDQUNAZ-OHDSQDQS2NDS": {
        "refid": null,
        "userref": 0,
        "status": "open",
        "starttm": 0,
        "expiretm": 0,
        "descr": {
          "ordertype": "limit",
          "price": "9",
          "price2": "0",
          "leverage": "none",
          "close": ""
        },
        "vol": "1.00000000",
        "vol_exec": "0.00000000",
        "cost": "0.00000",
        "fee": "0.00000",
        "price": "0.00000",
        "stopprice": "0.00000",
        "limitprice": "0.00000",
        "misc": "",
        "oflags": "fciq"
      }
    }
  }
}"""

data = json.loads(inStr)
print(data['result']['open'].keys())
```